# Setting a dictionary key as an object type

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics, pass-by-reference

Is it ok to set the key of a dictionary to a reference type? Does the dictionary store the references of those objects or does it store the object instances?
I have a dictionary and I am storing if the lists are loaded or not as a boolean value; If it actually stores the massive lists, It will be troublesome.

```
public Dictionary<object, bool> isloaded;
```

Comment: You need to implement `GetHashCode` with a custom type as key when you don't want to compare by reference only. Why do you need an `Object` as key instead of a strongly typed key?

Comment: Based on this:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx  they key can be any type.  Technically strings are reference types and they are frequently used as keys.  However I think a key should be strongly typed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's perfectly ok - it only stores the reference, not a copy.

However, you have to be careful that after inserting a key object, you don't change any of the fields of the key object that are used to calculate the key's GetHashCode().

This is because the object's GetHashCode() is used to generate the integer key that is used internally as the key. Clearly, if that changes after the key has been inserted, it will be in the wrong place and Bad Things will happen.

(I personally think you should only ever use immutable objects for keys.)

Comment: +1 because you thought of the same issues as I did in my answer, in the same order ;-)

Comment: It's not a matter of opinion... items stored in hashtables (i.e. `Dicitonary<TK,TV>` should always be immutable, or at the very least, the properties that participate in equality/hashing should be immutable. The consequence of failing to observe this is that it becomes trivial to corrupt the dictionary by mutating the key.

Comment: my "objects" will not ever be reconstructed during the execution. I guess it wont be a problem then.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is "ok".

The dictionary stores references; it does not copy the instances.

Note that this can be problematic if the key objects are mutable and get changed in a way that their hash codes would change. Also note that whatever the reference type used as a key is, their `GetHashCode()` method should have a meaningful implementation.